# Name of a lattice-property

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology, notation, lattice-theory

Assume that we have a complete lattice $(L,\leq)$.

I would like to know whether the following property has a specific name and whether lattices with this property have been studied somewhere:

For each $x,y \in L$ with $x < y$, there exist $u, v \in L$ 
such that $v$ is completely join-irreducible, $u$ its unique lower cover (w.r.t to $\leq$) and $v \wedge x \leq u$ as well as $v \leq y$.

It might be helpful to point out that this is equivalent to the condition that each element of $L$ is the join of completely join-irreducible elements. My feeling is that there should be a name for such a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faigle and Herrmann call them point-lattices. They are useful in the modular, algebraic case
(Faigle embedding theorem) and also more generally in the (strongly) semi-modular algebraic
case (generalized matroid lattices).

Comment: Thank you very much. If that is not too much trouble, could you give me a reference?

Comment: http://www.springerlink.com/content/h38122511085g364/


Comment: Great, thank you very much for this answer and the reference.